# Google Drive API V3 List Files From Hierarchy Of Specif Folder using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have been struggling with google drive to find out a way to get all files exist in a specific folder and its children folder.

I want to get all files exist in Folder2. Folder21 and folder22 are child folders contain files. it should also get files exist in these folders 21 and 22.

Files.get by using root in parent return all folders and files

but i want to get all files and folder hierarchy of a specific folder.
Here is my code

```
 var retrievePageOfChildren = function (request, result) {
            request.execute(function (resp) {
                result = result.concat(resp.items);
                var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
                if (nextPageToken) {
                    request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                        'q': "'0Bzhp8zV0Leq1c0VTWU55c25MeGc' in parents and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
                        'pageToken': nextPageToken,
                        'fields': 'parents'
                    });
                    retrievePageOfChildren(request, result);
                } else {
                    debugger;
                    return deferred.resolve(result);  
                }
            });
        }

        var initialRequest = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            'q': "'0Bzhp8zV0Leq1c0VTWU55c25MeGc' in parents and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
            'fields': 'parents'
        });
        retrievePageOfChildren(initialRequest, []);
```

Please help me

Comment: what have you tried so far? Post your code so we can help you fix it. Otherwise we don't know which part of the task is causing the problem.

Comment: ok thanks. if using the files.get gets them all, why not just filter through the JSON once you've received all the data? Then you only need 1 ajax request, and you can find the specific folder just by looping through the data.

Comment: Thanks Adyson . but  drive contains thousands of files and folder contains just few number of files. Getting data of full drive and then loop it to find files of specific folder may take time. 2ndly how we find that this file exist in specific folder. fils list retrieve by this method does not contain parent info

Comment: well if you remove "and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'" from your query, that will give you all the files _and_ folders in the parent folder. Then you can look through that to find any folders, and make more queries to get the files in those folders. That would be my suggestion.

Comment: Hi Adyson, thanks for suggestion but i need something else that is more efficient

Comment: looking at how the API works in the documentation I don't think there is one. Good luck if you can find it.